# How to report a E_USER_NOTICE with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I would like to report a notice, not an error in this code:

```
public function save(array $options = [])
{
    if($this->checkDuplicate()) {
        report(new \Exception("File already exists {$this->hash}"));
        return;
    }

    // continue save ...
}
```

Unfortunately the syntax `report(new \Exception(''))` reports a `local.ERROR` not a `E_USER_NOTICE`.

How to report a `E_USER_NOTICE` with Laravel?

[Magnus Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson) suggested to use `trigger_error` like:

```
    if($this->checkDuplicate()) {
        report(trigger_error("File already exists {$this->hash}"));
        return;
    }
```

Unfortunately it does not work because the execution is broken:

```
$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> function foo() {
...     report(new \Exception('whoops'));
...     return 42;
... }
>>> function bar() {
...     report(trigger_error('whoops'));
...     return 42;
... }
>>> $u = bar()
PHP Notice:  whoops in ...
>>> echo $u
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: u in ...
>>> $v = foo()
[2019-01-22 10:27:26] local.ERROR: whoops {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0) ...
=> 42
>>> echo $v
42⏎
```

Comment: Try using the [trigger_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trigger-error.php)-function. `trigger_error("File already exists {$this->hash}", E_USER_NOTICE);`

Comment: Absolutely, but it is not a Laravel function :(

Comment: So? Why would that matter? Laravel is just a framework written in PHP. `new \Exception()` isn't Laravel either.

Comment: Whooh! You mean `report(trigger_error('test'))`. Well it works :)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have edited my question with your solution and showed it does not work :(

Comment: Why are you using `report()`? Doesn't the notice get logged anyway?

Comment: Simply because it does not work with `trigger_error` alone :)

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct level set in `error_reporting(E_NOTICE)` and that the logger has the [correct error level configured](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging). Set it to `notice` there as well.